# Spring AOP execution not working for multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I want to log every request mapping in my aspect method with    `@Before("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")`

this execution formula just works for pathvariable method with 1 parameter ( so which is `/people/{id}`).

For multiple variable ones in this case for ex  `getAllPeople method` this aspect method not firing. How can I make a fire aspect method with every request with 1 parameter or more? Thanks in advance.

My App Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/people") 
    private ResponseEntity<People> getAllPeople(@RequestParam(name = "page", required = false) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", required = false) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(name = "sortBy", required = false) Boolean sortByNameOrEpCount)

    System.out.println("getall works");

} 

@GetMapping("/people/{id}") 
    private ResponseEntity<People> getPeople(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id)

    System.out.println("getpeople works");
ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

My aspect file:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AppAspect {

    @Before("execution(@(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *) * *(..))")
    public void loggingEndPointRequests(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("loggingEndPointRequests" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: You'r methods need to be public for Spring AOP being able to intercept those methods. I'm actually suprised you are event stating that this works.

Comment: Thank you i couldn't realized that